# spring boot problems with aop and controller

Tags: java, controller, spring-boot

when i use spring boot,the aop couldn't be effective with annotation controller , how can i best do it ?

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Configuration
public class MethodStatisticsPointcutAspect {

    @Resource
    private CounterService counterService;

    // aop defined
    @Around("@annotation(com.xxx.xxx.metrics.annotation.MethodStatistics)")
    private void around(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
        // do sth
    }
}
```

my controller defined like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/usertest")
public class UserTestController {

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    @MethodStatistics
    String test() {
       // do sth
   }
}
```

i wish to use aop manager all the methods with annotation @MethodStatistics,but it couldn't work with @controller at all~

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I'm not sure what your question is, nor what problem you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the runtime aop binding in spring (and spring-boot) can only interpose on public methods.  if you want to interpose on a protected, private, or package protected method, you have to use the aspectj code weaver instead of the spring implemented runtime proxying.

i stumbled upon this in my own project until i read the doc's that pointed this out (my method was protected)

from the docs: [ http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html ]

> Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring’s AOP framework, protected
>   methods are by definition not intercepted, neither for JDK proxies
>   (where this isn’t applicable) nor for CGLIB proxies (where this is
>   technically possible but not recommendable for AOP purposes). As a
>   consequence, any given pointcut will be matched against public methods
>   only!
>
> If your interception needs include protected/private methods or even
>   constructors, consider the use of Spring-driven native AspectJ weaving
>   instead of Spring’s proxy-based AOP framework. This constitutes a
>   different mode of AOP usage with different characteristics, so be sure
>   to make yourself familiar with weaving first before making a decision.